# Request Update phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql

I want Update an `SQL table`in phpMyAdmin, to change a values of a column.
My request is:

```
Update article set Id_LRU where ID_Article='DIEPRESTATION'
```

It return an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where ID_Article='DIEPRESTATION'' at line 1
```

I changed it by using `like` because the type of the field is a `Varchar`:

```
Update article set Id_LRU where ID_Article like 'DIEPRESTATION'
```

Also it got the same error.
How can I correct it please .

Comment: Writing "mysql update" on Google, and choising one of the link obtained (eg. the second one): https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp   or the third one https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error.

```
Update article set Id_LRU ='YOURVALUE' where ID_Article like 'DIEPRESTATION'
```

Try above query.